# How do I pass values to an html template using consolidate.swig in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, swig-template

This is my code:

```
var cons = require('consolidate');
var list = new Array();
cons.swig("views/Categories.html", {categorylist: list}, 
        function(err, html) {
            response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type" : "text/html"});
            response.end(html);
        });
```

I needed to pass the array to the Categories.html page. Then the array must be manipulable in the Categories.html page. How do I do that? Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tested this? Because it should work.

Comment: Of course, do not forget to install swig itself with `npm install swig`.

Comment: Can I manipulate it on the HTML page just like a Javascript array?

Comment: Depends on what you mean with "manipulate". If you want to loop thru and read their values, yeah, of course. If you want to push items and other nasty things, no.

Comment: Are you wanting to use the data in JavaScript on the page or something? Swig has a `|json` filter that you could use to do that if you wanted, like `<script>var categoryList = {{ categoryList|json }};</script>`.